# Count words with the Map/Reduce algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, count, cpu-word, reduce

If there are 20 words to count. Every 5 words a group, these groups are handled by different computer nodes. Well, if "boy" this word appeared twice, but divided in different groups, what kind of algorithm did the Map/Redude used to get the actual number of the word "boy".

Answer (score 2):

In this example, the most obvious way to compute this using Map/Reduce would be that each mapper got 5 words, then emits the word to the reducers. The words would be split between the reducers, so that reducer 1 gets all the "boy" words, reducer 2 gets all the "the" words etc., the reducer can then simply sum up the words it received to get the number of occurrences of that word.

There's an example of this in the Hadoop documentation: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v1.0

Answer (score 0):

That's the reduce in MapReduce. The master node would take the occurrence counts in each subgroup and combine them by adding the occurrence for each word. So if there are four groups, and 'boy' occurs in two of them exactly once each, it would combine them by adding the occurrences to get a total of 1+1+0+0=2.